# Adding Material Button in XML causing app to crash

Tags: android, user-interface, button, material-design, android-design-library

When I add the following code to the layout.xml file, the app crashes, when the layout is loaded.

Code:

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/b_p_add"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_p_addl_notes"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />
```

I checked my app gradle file and found

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

So, the required design, support, appcompat dependencies are present.

Note: No other code apart from the above has been added, i.e, the app works fine if I don't add the Material button in XML and crashes, if I add the Material Button in the XML.

Answer (score 14):

Please change your app theme from:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

to

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">`

for MaterialButton to work, your app theme must inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Comment: Worked. Thanks! I have a doubt. Will changing the style make my app incompatible with all devices running less than API 21? App Compat is required for devices running API 7 and above right? Although, I could place the style in styles-v21 folder, how should I handle having MaterialButton in XML? I'm not sure if I can have 2 different layout.xml for v-21 and below